# redirecting ww.domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

hey I have a problem with redirecting my site.
I want to redirect:

```
ww.domain.com
```

to

```
www.domain.com
```

but I cant seem to get it to work.
I have tried searching all over the internet and all I seem to get is this code which doesnt work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(ww?\.)?domain\.com(:\d+)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$`. That will match any domain that is not exactly www.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(ww\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it didnt seem to work. The ww.domain.com still came up as not found.
Is there anything else I need to do instead of just mod_rewrite?

Comment: Please make sure: 1. mod_rewrite is enabled and 2. .htaccess is enabled

Comment: hi, both are enabled as I am currently rewriting other links.

Comment: You're saying `ww.domain.com` came as not found. Can that really be a resolved as a valid URL? Can you rename your .htaccess (or comment it) and then retry `ww.domain.com` to see if it loads or not?